# Neo4j - Querying with Lucene

Tags: lucene, indexing, full-text-search, neo4j

I am using Neo4j embedded as database. I have to store thousands of articles daily and and I need to provide a search functionality where I should return the articles whose content match to the keywords entered by the users. I indexed the content of each and every article and queried on the index like below

```
val articles = article_content_index.query("article_content", search string)
```

This works fine. But, its taking lot of time when the search string contains common words like "the", "a" and etc which will be present in each and every article.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Probably a lucene issue.

You can configure your own analyzer which could leave off those frequent (stop-)words:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html 
http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html
http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html

Answer (score 1):

You might configure `article_content_index` as fulltext index, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html. To switch to using fulltext index, you first have to remove the index and the first usage of `IndexManager.forNodes(String, Map)` needs to configure the index on creation properly.

Comment: am already using fulltext index ("article_content", Some(Map("provider" -> "lucene", "type" -> "fulltext")))

Comment: consider specifying a special analyzer that prevents words like 'the', 'a' from being present in the index. Lucene documentation should give some hints.

Comment: In that case I don't get any results if the search string is just "the" or "a" !

Comment: typically you remove the short words from both the data to index as well as from the query strings. Your use case seems to be different. If you want to search for "the" you need to be aware that it might be time consuming.